# extract value from paragraph tag to pass it by gtag to pixel

Tags: javascript, pixel, gtag.js

I am trying to setup Purchase event for facebook pixel using gtag , but the website seems that they dont use data layer , they just print

```
<p class="text_msg">this is to confirm that you have paid <strong>1</strong> USD as donations</p>
```

how can i get the number 1 and save it in a value , which all of this text can be taken using the class name . but in order for me to pass the value to the purchase event its should be number.

I have tried like below ways :

```
function () {
 return trim({{Click Element}}.parentNode.innerText);
}
```

but nothing worked !

Answer (score 0):

since the number is inside the  tag you can use querySelector to select the  inside the

, with innerText you get the text and with Number() you convert the string to number. The code snippet is this:

```js
const textMessage = document.querySelector(".text_msg > strong")
const quantity = Number(textMessage.innerText)

console.log(quantity)
```

```html
<p class="text_msg">
  this is to confirm that you have paid <strong>1</strong> USD as donations
</p>
```

Comment: I have found another way to do it using DOM ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxEYZthbzp4 )